# Get subitem of subitems

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Playlist
    (`id` int, `name` varchar(90))
;
    
INSERT INTO Playlist
    (`id`, `name`)
VALUES
    (1, 'Playlist_1'),
    (100, 'EmptyPlaylist'),
    (111, 'Playlist_222'),
    (1001, 'Playlist_4')
;

CREATE TABLE PlaylistItem
    (`id` int, `trackID` int, `playlistID` int)
;
    
INSERT INTO PlaylistItem
    (`id`, `trackID`, `playlistID`)
VALUES
    (3, 2, 1),
    (32, 22, 1),
    (321, 222, 1),
    (333, 222, 3),
    (333, 2, 3),
    (303, 200, 1001)
;

CREATE TABLE Track
    (`id` int, `title` varchar(300))
;
    
INSERT INTO Track
    (`id`, `title`)
VALUES
    (2, 'Foo'),
    (22, 'Bar'),
    (200, 'Only_In_Playlist_4_Which_Is_Not_Included_In_the_Query'),
    (222, 'Byy'),
    (21, 'NotInAnyPlaylist'),
    (20000, 'NotInAnyPlaylist_2')
;
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/068d3f)

Each `Playlist` contains multiple `PlaylistItem` , which contain one `Track`. My goal is to provide an array of `Playlist IDs` and get all `Tracks` inside those playlist (not only their IDs).

However, I do not know how to access subitems from a query. I used joins but they merge the keys and I only want to get the tracks without the keys from other tables. I could select just the keys from `Track` with a join, but my `Track` table has over 100 keys and they could change.

Desired outcome :

| id | title |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | Foo |
| 22 | Bar |
| 222 | Byy |

I get track IDs now with this:

```
SELECT 
  trackID
FROM
  PlaylistItem
WHERE
  playlistID in ('1', '4') -- Here comes the array of IDs, for the example I want '1' and '4'
```

Comment: [ask]
[Tips for asking a good Structured Query Language (SQL) question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271055)

Comment: @PChemGuy I added a fiddle and what I tried. Is this good now?

Comment: That's better. You also need to show a table with desired result

Comment: I do not see how your target is different from the content of the Track table

Comment: @PChemGuy I see, I will rework this.

Comment: And you need to clearly state your problem. Right now you do not even mention it.

Comment: @PChemGuy All done. Asking good questions is hard

Comment: Will likely be easier next time ;) Thanks for editing and improving your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your description is correct now and you didn't miss to tell us anything important, you just need to `JOIN` your tables and select those columns that should be shown.

This query will produce exactly the outcome you described:

```
SELECT p.id, t.title
FROM playlist p
JOIN PlaylistItem tp
ON p.id = tp.playlistID
JOIN track t 
ON t.id = tp.trackID;
```

You can verify this here: [db<>fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/5e36c0/2)

If you need a condition which playlists should be shown, you can add a `WHERE` clause or add the condition to the first `JOIN`. Doing this in the `WHERE` clause is mostly better readable, doing it in the `JOIN` can reduce the query's execution time.

For example, if you want to show playlists 1 and 4 only:

```
SELECT p.id, t.title
FROM playlist p
JOIN PlaylistItem tp
ON p.id = tp.playlistID
JOIN track t 
ON t.id = tp.trackID
WHERE p.id IN (1,4);
```

OR:

```
SELECT p.id, t.title
FROM playlist p
JOIN PlaylistItem tp
ON p.id = tp.playlistID AND p.id IN (1,4)
JOIN track t 
ON t.id = tp.trackID;
```

If not only the track's id, but also further columns from this table should be shown, add those columns to the selection:

```
SELECT p.id, t.title, t.column2, t.column3,...
FROM playlist p
JOIN PlaylistItem tp
ON p.id = tp.playlistID
JOIN track t 
ON t.id = tp.trackID
WHERE p.id IN (1,4);
```

You could also just write ...,t.*, but using * is [not recommended](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3639861/why-is-select-considered-harmful).

A last note: Like forpas showed, in your specific case, you even could use just one `JOIN`. My answer assumed that's because you just showed a small part of your real data and you need all tables in a real scenario. But you should of course check this and if really not required, remove the second `JOIN`.

Comment: This works for the example, but I my real 'Track' table has lots of keys (I added this information later, so you might have not seen it). And I might also want to change the keys in the future

Comment: But changing the SELECT to t.* works (in the second and third example)! Can you edit your answer to that so that I can accept it?

Comment: @Woww I edited the answer...using * is mostly no good idea, you should better set a proper column selection.

Answer (score 1):

You only need 1 join:

```
SELECT p.id, t.*
FROM track t INNER JOIN PlaylistItem p
ON p.trackID = t.id
WHERE p.playlistID IN (1, 4);
```